# Change href attribute by jQuery in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating an application by jQuery Mobile.

I want a link, which redirects to a page. for example:

```
<a href="/Account/" data-transition="turn" class="useroptions">Account</a>
```

It is available on all of pages, and I want to change `href` of that link on every page to something like this:

```
<a href="/Account/?returnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2FAbout" data-transition="turn" class="useroptions">Account</a>
```

I have written this code, but it is not working **when jQuery Mobile loads a page with Ajax navigation**:

```
$(function () {
    $(".useroptions").attr("href", "/Account/?returnUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(document.URL));
});
```

How to do that when every page is shown? (Which event should I use? ...)

Comment: You probably have to listen to the `pageinit` event, according to the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Comment: I am using *prefetching* in some pages, So that event is not usable. I need an event that runs when page actually **shows**...

Comment: Maybe `pageshow` can solve my problem. see this: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html  But I don't know how to apply that event for **all of my pages**. not one by one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use `pageshow` event of jQuery Mobile. see `pageshow` part of [this](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) page.

Modified version of jQuery code to work correctly:

```
$("div[data-role='page']").live("pageshow",function() {
    $(".useroptions").attr("href", "/Account/?returnUrl=" + encodeURIComponent(document.URL));
});
```